# getting questions questioned shouldn't be so easy...answered shouldn't be so hard

Tags: support

I am new to this site. I wanted to ask a valid question. I doctored the question repeatedly in order to get seemingly errant "quality" messages to stop. Finally succeeded. But then the "no user name" and/or "email address already registered" blurbs kept appearing (even after valid rabbit response), in spite of valid credentials in all possible permutations. (By the weigh, the address-registered blurb is ambiguous in that it uses a positive when it means a negative...valid registration in blurb form ought to be a good thing, but is a bad thing.)

Finding nothing would work, I checked the P3P report to see if all was still well with allowing the stackexchange domain cookie. No problem there, either, but a blocked cookie (with no requisite antecedant cookie request) did appear:  quantserve...pixel.quantserve. Since these seemed dubious (having not requesting download permission not shown stackexchange affiliation, and possibly being more than just a statistics service) I requested the privacy policy, but to no avail.

I was advised instead to check with you (via "contact") for the privacy policy.

The following...

> Please, provide that policy, with explanation and purpose, if you have
>   it. Also, explain the on-again off-again problems (and related time
>   wasting) signing on or asking questions on this (english especially)
>   site. I especially get annoyed at composing good posts only to have to
>   rewrite them from memory when seem to just evaporate on the way to or
>   from the server. Thanks.

...was to have been my inquiry; however there seemed to have been no means for straightforward contact...and then, even after being "redirected" to do so, I was blocked from posing any question here, for lack of registration credentials...the same which I was uncertain whether or not I had or did not have.

Eventually I was able to get to this point--whether that is good or bad I can't be certain (for example: as to whether or not I will face new and equally, or moreso fascinating participation conflicts).

Whatever info you can provide as to the re-quoted material above, and as to circumventing the obstacles which the site seems to provide in such abundance will be sincerely appreciated.

--Lex

Comment: I can confirm that the quantserve cookies is not required: I have it blocked, and I can log in. I have Javascript from quantserve blocked too, for good measure.

Comment: It would help if you could provide screenshots, or at least copies of the actual messages that you are getting in a step by step fashion.  I can't follow what you are saying is the problem.  Is this from trying to post on Meta, or the Main site?  Particularly this "I was blocked from posing any question here, for lack of registration credentials"—would benefit from a screenshot.

Comment: It may help to know if you're on a public or work computer, as well. Is there any software installed that could cause issues with your browser? Also, "Stop trying to make *by the weigh* happen! It's not going to happen!" (joking) :b

Answer (score 6):

The privacy policy is linked at the bottom of each and every page: http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy

I cannot reproduce your problems with posting:

- When I tried to submit a question that did not meet the quality standards, the post was retained in its entirety.
- When I tried to submit a question while logged out without providing name and/or email, the post was retained in its entirety.
- When I tried to submit a question that hit the CAPTCHA (the rabbit, as you put it), the post was retained in its entirety.

Nevertheless, if you find that your posts are being consistently lost somehow (possibly a browser issue?), I suggest you compose your post locally, such as on Microsoft Word, Textedit, Notepad, or a similar program, so that you can copy and paste it if the post is lost.

The low quality standards filter is designed to deny questions that are, quite frankly, of low quality. If you find your question is being blocked by that filter, I would only suggest that you spend a little more time composing it, paying proper attention to generally accepted rules of English, such as capitalization and punctuation.

Comment: I have had instance when the autosave feature worked...if only the save had come soon enough to that so much didn't need recomposing. Is it a timed save (like a word processor)? If so, is there a user way to invoke the save more often? Sometimes the save seeminly fails when I request another (eg, "research") site and the stack exchange just goes away--and evidently looses any saved matter. I was able to work around that by diminishing the exchange page (out of the address bar) by that does not always work has hoped. I think...[continued (please wait)]

Comment: The draft saves every 45 seconds, and you can manually save if you install [this script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2086/manual-draft-save-save-a-draft-on-demand). However, if you're submitting a post to the server and it denies the post, it should return the post to you in the edit box even if the draft has not saved. You can only have one draft at any time on a site, and composing a new post will overwrite the previous draft (the draft feature is there to save a post if your browser crashes or something; it is not meant to be relied on permanently, however).

Comment: ...part of the problem might be a compatability issue relating to tabbed browsing. My browser is set up for pages but the site seems to support only tabs. So that could explain why inadvertent dropping of the site leads to lost messages. It could also be that my browser has been modified (respecting tabbed browsing) in the background, and without consent.

Comment: Based on what you're saying, I suspect the problem is that you switch between different post boxes in different windows, which will confuse the draft feature. I would highly suggest that you only work on one post at any given time, in one window, without editing any other textbox on that particular Stack Exchange site until you've submitted that post.

Comment: Thanks for the save into and the script. Any thoughts about the problem with getting recognized? Will registration relieve that problem? Does it persist between log-outs? Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you should log in before trying to post. You can check whether you're logged in by glancing at the header; if you see your username, you're logged in, and you shouldn't be prompted for your name or email. If you see "log in" instead, click that and log in before you ask your question (if you've already written your question at that point, however, use the "log in" link at the bottom of the "Ask Question" page, and copy your question text in case it doesn't save).

Comment: as for hopping between posts, I don't recall that's being the case. A typical example would be going to consult a Web source while a post composition is in progress...the site likes so much to have authenticatiions even from old pike travellers like me.

Comment: I'm in accord on verifying personal "masthead" and such. I had supposed the site would always recognize my machine; and I typically come here using history or old email link. But, today's problem was with regards to logging (openly) after the fact of clicking the question submit button. Is it a case of "once registered" I am thenceforth duty bound to log in?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're asking. Generally, the site should remember you, but if you clear your cookies or log out, you will have to log in again.

Answer (score 1):

It does rather sound as though you are not allowing persistent cookies.

If you set your browser's cookie policy so that all cookies are removed at the end of a session, you will always have to log in. However, if you have two English.SE windows/tabs open, and close one of them, the browser will remove the relevant cookies and that will upset the other window.

Quite how this works does depend too on your login authentication: logging in using a Google account rather than SE may behave differently; although presumably your aggressive third-party-cookie policy means you're not doing that.